# how to map json to java object having a different structure using jackson mixins

Tags: java, json, jackson

How to convert this json

```
{
    "name": "abc",
    "city": "xyz"
}
```

to employee object using Jackson mixin

```
//3rd party class//
public class Employee {
    public String name;
    public Address address;
}

//3rd party class//
public class Address {
    public String city;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you would annotate the `address` field with `@JsonUnwrapped` to be unwrapped when serialized (and wrapped when deserialized). But as you cannot change your 3rd party classes, you have to do this on a mixin instead:

```
// Mixin for class Employee
abstract class EmployeeMixin {
    @JsonUnwrapped public Address address;
}
```

Then, create a module that holds all your specific "extensions". This can be done by subclassing `Module` or `SimpleModule`, or by composing a `SimpleModule` as here:

```
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("Employee");
module.setMixInAnnotation(Employee.class, EmployeeMixin.class);
```

Third, register the module with your `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Last, have fun serializing/deserializing!

---

Self contained, complete example that subclasses `SimpleModule`:

```
public class TestJacksonMixin {

    /* 3rd party */
    public static class Employee {
        public String name;
        public Address address;
    }

    /* 3rd party */
    public static class Address {
        public String city;
    }

    /* Jackon Module for Employee */
    public static class EmployeeModule extends SimpleModule {
        abstract class EmployeeMixin {
            @JsonUnwrapped
            public Address address;
        }

        public EmployeeModule() {
            super("Employee");
        }

        @Override
        public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
            setMixInAnnotation(Employee.class, EmployeeMixin.class);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.name = "Bob";
        emp.address = new Address();
        emp.address.city = "New York";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new EmployeeModule());

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(emp));
    }
}
```

See [Jackson Annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations)